# Multiple Permissions Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I want to build java class that managing all my permissions
I start with ReadContacts from Phone
Permissions.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class Permissions {


    public void checkPermission(Context t, Activity s) {
        //check condition
  
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(t, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //when permission is not granted
            //Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(s,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},100);

        }else{
            //when permission is granted
            //create method

        }
    }



}
```

and I pass from MainActivity the Context and activity

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Permissions permissions;
    Context appContext;
    Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        appContext = getApplicationContext();


        permissions.checkPermission(appContext,MainActivity.this);
    }


    private void checkPermission() {
        //check condition

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //when permission is not granted
            //Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},100);

        }else{
            //when permission is granted
            //create method
            Toast.makeText(this,"permission Access",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

}
```

and what it's does is crashing my app
I know that my problem it when I pass
the context and the activity , I try to only
send the activity and its also crashing my app

Thanks for Assistance

Comment: Please add the crash log from logcat as well

Comment: Use Dexter library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not instantiated the `permissions` of type `Permissions` in your MainActivity class. Thus you're calling the `checkPermission()` method on a `null object reference`.

### Possible Fixes

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Permissions permissions;
    Context appContext;
    Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        permissions = new Permissions();
        permissions.checkPermission(appContext,MainActivity.this);
    }
    
    // Rest of the code...
}
```

#### Alternatively...

You can alternatively declare the `checkPermission` method as *static* to be able to call it without instantiating.

```java
public class Permissions {

    public static void checkPermission(Context t, Activity s) {
        //check condition
  
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(t, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //when permission is not granted
            //Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(s,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},100);

        }else{
            //when permission is granted
            //create method

        }
    }
}
```

then you call it in the MainActivity like following

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    Context appContext;
    Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        Permissions.checkPermission(appContext,MainActivity.this);
    }
    
    // Rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Okay, so how can i fix this?

Comment: @NMZ updated the unswer with code.

Comment: hey when did you think I need to write onrequestpermission func in the main or in the permissions class?

Comment: I did not get your question. When did I think?

Comment: when you use a permissions you need to write this function:  when you use a permissions you need to write this function:  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(...)

you think I need to put this func in the main class or in permissions class?        

you think I need to put this func in the main class or in permissions class?

Comment: Aha got it now. You must implement it in your main activity because your Permission class is not a derivative of the activity class.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it helped to solve your problem. At least untile a new better answer has presented.